# What's the easiest and fastest way of get a site's info (all combo box combinations at once)

Tags: html, bots

What's the easiest and fastest way of get a site's info automatically choosing it's combo boxes?

Hear in Brazil we have fipe's site: http://www.fipe.org.br/web/indices/veiculos/default.aspx?p=51 which lists used car prices, BUT it needs too much human interaction:

first you select the company, then related models are loaded. Also is needed to set up the car's year.

How to get all the prices for all company's cars without any interaction? Like a bot, creating a table of all company cars prices at once?

Example

```
COMPANY >       MODEL        > YEAR > PRICE
Nissan  > Altima GXE 2.4 16V > 1993 > 7325.00
Nissan  > Altima GXE 2.4 16V > 1994 > 8223.00
Nissan  > Altima SE 2.4 16v  > 1995 > 11783.00
```

How to get all combo box combinations at once? Any tool?

Comment: Do you want all the content of all the dropboxes on the webpage you showed ?

Comment: Yes, all Company's cars * years

Comment: You can dig into scrapy, a very powerfull crawling framework in python -> [scrapy homepage](http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. Want to but this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone just did it, take a look if **thats** what you are looking for (click here).](http://www.deixaeuprogramar.com/2/post/2013/07/tabela-fipe-recuperando-dados.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can dig into scrapy, a very powerfull crawling framework in python -> [scrapy homepage](http://scrapy.org/)
;)